# How to open downloaded file in xamarin forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

In my Xamarin forms, I download a file in the Android App using Web client. It saved in the local folder. 
This will mention using the android notification as below code

```
            webClient.DownloadFile(filePath, localPath);
            Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(Android.App.Application.Context)
.SetContentTitle("Download Successfully")
.SetContentText("Click here to open")
.SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.abc_btn_colored_material);
            Notification notification = builder.Build();
            NotificationManager notificationManager =
Android.App.Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService) as NotificationManager;
            const int notificationId = 0;
            notificationManager.Notify(notificationId, notification);
```

I want to open the downloaded file from the notification. How could i do that. I am new to the Xamarin. Please Suggest a solution.

Answer (score 1):

For your notification you can create a `PendingIntent` with an `Intent`, which has Action View on the file. This would look something like:

```
var mimeTypeMap = MimeTypeMap.Singleton;
var mimeType = mimeTypeMap.GetMimeTypeFromExtension(System.IO.Path.GetExtension(filePath));

var intent = new Intent();
intent.SetAction(Intent.ActionView);
intent.SetDataAndType(Android.Net.Uri.Parse(filePath), mimeType);

var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntentFlags.OneShot);
```

Then you set that `Intent` in your `Notification` builder:

```
notification.SetContentIntent(pendingIntent);
```

Now, the filePath you give the `Intent` must be somewhere that is accessible from all applications on Android, otherwise opening it will fail. So when you save the file, save it to External Storage in a public place.

Comment: new Android.Net.Uri(filePath) shows can not create instance of the abstract class of interface Uri

Comment: Sorry it should be `Uri.Parse(filePath)`.

Answer (score 0):

I use this

```
var docSaved = await DisplayActionSheet("Saved", "Open", "Ok", "File was successfull);
   switch (docSaved)
   {
         case "Open":
         {
             Device.OpenUri(new Uri(Your_FilePath));
             break;
         }
         case "Ok":
         {
            break;
         }                   
   }
```